# Why do I get this error in Clang? "constexpr if condition is not a constant expression"

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, c++17, clang

I am trying to compile a class using Clang:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdlib>

struct foo
 {
  template <class T, class... Ts>
  struct is_any: std::disjunction <std::is_same <T, Ts>... >{};
       
  template<typename T, std::size_t N>
  static constexpr bool is_pointer_to_const_char(T(&)[N])
  { 
      return std::is_same_v<const char, T>;
  }
  
  template<typename T>
  static constexpr bool is_pointer_to_const_char(T &&)
  { 
      return std::is_same_v<const char *, T>;
  }
  
  template <class T>
  static constexpr bool is_str( const T& obj )
   {
    return is_pointer_to_const_char( obj ) || is_any<T, std::string, std::string_view>::value;
   }
  
  static constexpr bool is_escape_v( const std::string_view& str )
   {
    return ! str.rfind( "\033", 0 );
   }
  
  template <class T>
  inline bool is_escape( const T& str ) const
   {
    if constexpr ( is_str( str ) ) return is_escape_v( str );
    return false;
   }
 };

int main()
 {
  foo obj;
  obj.is_escape( "test" );
 }
```

But I get the following error:

```
prove.cpp:36:28: error: constexpr if condition is not a constant expression
    if constexpr ( is_str( str ) ) return is_escape_v( str );
                           ^
prove.cpp:44:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'foo::is_escape<char [5]>' requested here
  obj.is_escape( "test" );
      ^
1 error generated.
```

It seems that it doesn't like the `constexpr` qualifier I used in the `if` condition in the `is_escape()` method.

Did I do something wrong in the class method's definition?

My Clang version is 10.0.0-4.

Comment: Function parameters(like `str`) are not `constexpr`. GCC & MSVC both also gives the same error. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ph4j3c6rx)

Comment: @AnoopRana I edited the question: g++ works, but clang not. Which arguments you mean? of which function?

Comment: I meant function parameters instead of function argument. See my updated comment above. Also note **all three compilers(gcc, msvc and clang) give error**. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ph4j3c6rx)

Comment: Which version of GCC are you using?  GCC10 and above fail to compile this code.

Comment: @NathanOliver I compiled with g++ 9.4.0 and it works

Comment: @AnoopRana thanks. How could I solve this? If you make a full answer I could upvote it

Comment: @GianlucaBianco Working on it. For now, i have just pointed out the problem in my answer. Will add the solution soon.

Comment: @GianlucaBianco Btw are you still looking for that: `is_escape( "\033[31m" )` should give `true` and `is_escape( "hello" )` should give `false` and `is_escape(1)` should give `false`? If yes, do you mind if i suggest a simpler solution?

Comment: @AnoopRana yes I am still searching for them. Which solution are you talking about? If it works it's ok of course. I am struggling from the entire day on this problem lol

Comment: @GianlucaBianco See if [this demo](https://onlinegdb.com/qYEhIJ1wW) meets your requirement. I will add it in my answer if it does.

Comment: @AnoopRana it works! Awesome, thanks! Please edit the complete answer so I can choose it as the solution

Comment: @GianlucaBianco Added the solution in my answer. Check out the updated answer. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Did I do something wrong in the class method's definition?

The **problem** is that function parameters (like `str`) are not constant expressions. For example, we cannot use `str` as a template non-type parameter, or as a size of a built-in array.

This means the expression `is_str( str )` that contains the subexpression `str` is itself not a constant expression, either.

Moreover, the code is rejected by all the three major compilers, if you're using their latest versions. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ph4j3c6rx)

---

A simpler way of doing this would be as shown below:

```cpp
template <typename T>
bool is_escape(const T& str)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string>)
    {
        
        return ! std::string(str).rfind( "\033", 0 );
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
   
}
```

[Working demo](https://www.onlinegdb.com/qYEhIJ1wW)

---

Or just return `is_escape_v(str)`:

```
template <class T>
inline bool is_escape( const T& str ) const
{
    if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string_view>) 
    {
        return is_escape_v( str );
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/5PaIfIXSN)

Comment: Since `str` is a const ref, `std::string(str)` makes a copy of `str` when `str` is already a `std::string` and no copy should be needed. The OP's code wants to handle `const char*`, `std::string`, and `std::string_view` equally, so the code should convert to `std::string_view` instead (which is what `is_escape_v()` takes), eg: `if constexpr (is_any<T, const char*, std::string, std::string_view>::value) return is_escape_v( str );` or maybe just: `if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string_view>) return is_escape_v( str );`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I've added your 2nd suggestion in my answer. Btw the first suggestion where you're using `is_any` doesn't seem to give correct result. see [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/LhdZ7PITO). As you'll see in the demo linked above, the output is `0 0 0` when it should be `0 1 0`.

Comment: well, yeah, because the 1st suggestion was just an example, it is not looking for `char[N]`, like the OP'S original code tried to do. Add that and it works fine ([demo](https://onlinegdb.com/yC782LJ2u)), but it will require some more template hackery to support string literals of any length, ie `"test"` is returning 0 not because it isn't escaped but because `is_escape_v()` isn't be called in the first place.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah, i missed that.