# How to use an enum which constexpr?

Tags: c++, windows

How to use an enum which `constexpr`? [LIVE](https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/UZQkEra8-)

```
#include <iostream>

enum Color
{
   BLUE, RED
};

template <typename T>
auto Test(Color color, T etc)
{
    if constexpr (color == RED)
    {
        int x = 1;
    }
}

int main(){
    Test(RED, "abc");
}
```

The error being thrown is: `error: ‘color’ is not a constant expression` but `enums` arent const?

Comment: Function parameters like `color` are never constexpr. See [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73125275/why-do-i-get-this-error-in-clang-constexpr-if-condition-is-not-a-constant-expr?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I did not understand how the linked questions could help.

Comment: You can make `color` a non type template parameter and then it will work. See [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e8P3347fE) where i've made `color` a nontype template parameter.

Comment: `template <typename T, typename T> auto Test (T color, T etc)`?

Comment: See [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e8P3347fE) where i've made `color` a non type template parameter.

Comment: @JasonLiam is it 'bad practice' or undesirable or whatever, to write 'functions' in templates like this? https://pastebin.com/nGVb2J2K

Comment: It doesn't look like a bad practice. Nothing seems wrong or undesirable with your [link](https://pastebin.com/nGVb2J2K)