# Compile error: function parameter 'args' with unknown value cannot be used in a constant expression

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr, compile-time, fold-expression

I have this piece of code:

```
template <typename T>
struct Base {
    constexpr std::uint8_t getValue() noexcept {
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->getValueImpl();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
    friend struct Base<Derived>;

    constexpr std::uint8_t getValueImpl() noexcept {
        return sizeof(std::uint8_t);
    }
};

template <typename ...Args>
void doStuff(Args &&...args) {
    constexpr auto alrightVariable = sizeof...(args);
    constexpr auto errorVariable = (args.getValue() + ...);
}

int main() {
    doStuff(Derived());
    return 0;
}
```

And it throw compile error: "function parameter 'args' with unknown value cannot be used in a constant expression"

Where I was wrong? All variables can be calculated at compile time...

Comment: Function parameters are never constexpr. This means `args` in `args.getValue()` is not a compile time constant. See dupe: [Why do I get this error in Clang? "constexpr if condition is not a constant expression"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73125275/why-do-i-get-this-error-in-clang-constexpr-if-condition-is-not-a-constant-expr/73125474#73125474)

Comment: `constexpr alrightVariable = ` is not valid. What type `alrightVariable` supposed to have?

Comment: @JasonLiam sorry, fixed.

Comment: See the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73125275/why-do-i-get-this-error-in-clang-constexpr-if-condition-is-not-a-constant-expr/73125474#73125474). Function parameters like `args` are never `constexpr`.

Comment: This will be allowed in C++23, fixed via a defect report to the standard. If you let `doStuff` take its argument by-value it will work. This is an annoying issue specific to references.

Comment: To clarify: What I mean is that it will work when `args` is a non-reference _now_ and will work as reference as soon as compilers have implemented the defect report.

Comment: @user17732522 okay thanks, fix works! But in this case I also have a same error:
`template <typename ...Args>
std::uint32_t wrapper(Args ...args) {
    constexpr auto val = doStuff(args...);
    return val;
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto ret = wrapper(Derived());
    return ret;
}`

Comment: @in_text I don't know what you mean. Your `doStuff` is declared to return `void`, so that can't work.

Comment: @user17732522 
`template <typename ...Args>
constexpr std::uint32_t doStuff(Args ...args) {
    constexpr auto alrightVariable = sizeof...(args);
    constexpr auto errorVariable = (args.getValue() + ...);
    return alrightVariable + errorVariable;
}

template <typename ...Args>
std::uint32_t wrapper(Args ...args) {
    constexpr auto val = doStuff(args...);
    return val;
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto ret = wrapper(Derived());
    return ret;
}`

Comment: @in_text Missing `constexpr` on `wrapper`.